# Wrong search between dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

In the database I have table users which have column 'birthday'

Here is the sql query that I use to fetch the results

```
SELECT *
FROM (`users`)
WHERE `birthday` between '12/11/1982' and '31/01/1983'
```

The problems is that *I get records only for year 1982*?

Notice that records for 1983 year exists.

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: what is the data type of your column `birthday`, how is it formatted?

Comment: try to format data before doing between. read about [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) or TO_SECONDS().

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users\G` and post it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an alternative answer from Mark Byers. If the data type of your column `birthday` is `varchar` and has format of `dd/MM/yyyy`, please do read this; otherwise, read from [Mark Byer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13346170/491243).

The first thing you need to do is to convert your column into `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype by using `STR_TO_DATE`,

```
SELECT *
FROM  `users`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`birthday`,'%d/%m/%Y')
          between '1982-01-12' and '1983-12-31'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/616e9/11)

SOURCES

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [DATE formats](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

Answer (score 1):

You should put the year first in your date literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `birthday` between '1982-11-12' AND '1983-01-31'
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> Date and time values can be represented in several formats, such as quoted strings or as numbers, depending on the exact type of the value and other factors. For example, in contexts where MySQL expects a date, it interprets any of '2015-07-21', '20150721', and 20150721 as a date.

If you are using a `varchar` type then it still makes sense to put the date first (both in the data and in the query) because then your dates will sort correctly when using the default sorting order.

Comment: sql store date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, but he tries to search in "DD/MM/YYYY". Not even close to that. So, i guess, first step is conver date to unix timestamp or normal date stamp.